# Global Generic Field Update Event

Tags: acumatica

I have 50+ custom paired fields "Inches" and "Centimeters", each enabled and editable. I need to update "Inches" if the user changed the value of "Centimeters" and visa verse. I was able to do this using SetValuePending on one of the paired fields and SetValueExt on the other during the Field Updated Event. My question, is there a way to do this on a higher level without having to do a Field_Updated event for all the 100+ fields. I know that Formulas would create a circular reference so cannot be used. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use one method to handle `FieldUpdated` events for all fields you need using graph `FieldUpdated.AddHandler` method in constructor. To get a field name just extend a standard Acumatica FieldUpdated delegate with one additional parameter (`name` for example) and put it during the `FieldUpdated.AddHandler` call.
Here is an example with "Invoices and Memos" screen and `ARInvoiceEntry` graph.

```
public ARInvoiceEntry()
{
    FieldUpdated.AddHandler(typeof(ARTran), typeof(ARTran.inches).Name, (sender, e) => CommonFieldUpdated(sender, e, typeof(ARTran.inches).Name));
    FieldUpdated.AddHandler(typeof(ARTran), typeof(ARTran.centimeters).Name, (sender, e) => CommonFieldUpdated(sender, e, typeof(ARTran.centimeters).Name));
    ...
}

protected virtual void CommonFieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e, string name)
{
    // do something
}
```

Moreover, you can add handlers dynamically using fields collection for example

```
foreach(var field in Caches[typeof(ARTran)].Fields)
{
    // add handler depends on field name
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by `PXFormula` + `ExternalValue` BQL expression (the same as `PXRowUpdatedEventArgs.ExternalCall` for example), which will prevent circular reference between pair fields. The idea is to calculate field only when a related field has been changed by the user from UI (`ExternalCall` = true) and skip calculation when related field updated by the formula (`ExternalCall` = false).

```
public class centimetersInInches : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Constant<centimetersInInches>
{
    public centimetersInInches() : base(2.54m) { }
}

[PXDecimal]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Inches")]
[PXUnboundDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
[PXFormula(typeof(ExternalValue<Div<centimeters, centimetersInInches>>))]
public virtual decimal? Inches { get; set; }
public abstract class inches : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<inches> { }

[PXDecimal]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Centimeters")]
[PXUnboundDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]
[PXFormula(typeof(ExternalValue<Mult<inches, centimetersInInches>>))]
public virtual decimal? Centimeters { get; set; }
public abstract class centimeters : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<centimeters> { }
```

And aspx

```
<px:PXGridColumn DataField="Inches" CommitChanges="True" />
<px:PXGridColumn DataField="Centimeters" CommitChanges="True" />
```

Comment: Thanks, this is better than FieldUpdated, maybe the only solution available. I was hoping for something that calls a generic field update routine, and in the routine, it figures out what field was changed and then finds corresponding field name by removing "IN"/"CM" from the field name and adding "CM"/IN" and update that field to.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `RowUpdated` event and compare the old row with the new row to detect which field changed. I agree that keeping all logic in a single method is preferable.

```
public virtual void DAC_RowUpdated(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    DAC row = e.Row as DAC;
    DAC oldRow = e.OldRow as DAC;
    if (row == null || oldRow == null) return;

    // Compare old row with new row to determine which field changed
    if (row.Inches != oldRow.Inches)
    {
        // Inches field changed, update CM value
        row.CM = row.Inches * INCHES_TO_CM_CONSTANT;
    }

    // Add more conditions for the other fields
    [..]
}
```

> I know that Formulas would create a circular reference so cannot be
>   used.

Yes I wouldn't recommend it either, you could use the DAC property Setter though.

```
public string _Inches
public virtual string Inches
{
   get 
   { 
       return this._Inches; 
   }
   set 
   { 
       this._Inches = value;
       this.CM = value * INCHES_TO_CM_CONSTANT; 
   }
}
```

For all solution (except Formula/DAC attributes) I think a condition to stop recursion should be possible if it's absolutely necessary:

```
if (this.CM != value * INCHES_TO_CM_CONSTANT)
    this.CM = value * INCHES_TO_CM_CONSTANT;
```

Ideally proper use/avoidance of `SetValueExt` to control when events are raised (Ext method raises events) would be enough to stop infinite loops.

Comment: Thanks, as the customer has access to both fields, I wouldn't know which was updated last on the RowUpdated event if both were updated. I would need to do this on the FieldUpdated. I also cannot really check the current value with the new calculated value before making the change due to rounding.